# a dynamic program about subarray sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've see a problem about dynamic program
like this:

let's say there is a array like this: [600, 500, 300, 220, 210]
I want to find a sub array whose sum is the most closest to 1000 and bigger than it.(>=1000).

how can I write the code? I already understand the 01 backpack problem but still cannot make out this problem

Comment: Not sure if you mean "dynamic programming", nor if there is actually an efficient dynamic programming solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, I think you are referring to "dynamic programming", not "a dynamic program"; read up here if you want to know the difference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming

Second, I think you mean "closest to 1000 but NOT bigger than it (< 1000)", since that is the general constraint.  If you were allowed to go over 1000, then the problem doesn't make sense because there is no constraint.

Like the backpack problem, this is going to be a non-polynomial (NP) time problem (a problem where the time required to compute increases faster than polynomial growth - usually exponential or faster), where you would normally have to check every possible combination of numbers, which can take a long time for seemingly small set sizes.

I believe that the correct answer from the 5 you provided is 500+220+210, which sums to 930, the largest that you can make without going over 1000.

The basic idea of dynamic programming is to break the problem into smaller similar problems that are more easily computable; for example, if you had a million numbers and wanted to find the subset that is closest to 100000 but not over, you might divide the million into 100,000 subsets of 10 elements, and find the closest to a smaller number of each of those subsets, then use the resulting set of 100,000 sums to repeat with 10,000 sets, etc, until you reduce it to a close-but-not-perfect solution.

In any non-polynomial-time problem, dynamic programming can only be used in building a close approximation, since the solution isn't guaranteed to be optimal.

Comment: oh.thanks for telling me so much about dynamic programming, and it really help...but what I mean is indeed >=1000.  I want to find the smallest sum that over 1000.   for the example in [600, 500, 300, 220, 210], there are lots of sums >= 1000, but only 500 + 300 + 210 = 1010 is most smallest among the sums.

Comment: Miss Cindy has some collections. Nowadays she is lack of money and wants to sell some of the collections.
She lacks 1000 dollars, the collections values 300 600 220 210 500 180 ... and so on. 
Question: Design an algorithm for Miss Cindy to get enough money and also, the total price of the sold collections is the least(the input is an array of collections' values, while the output is the subset of it)

Comment: good example, that explains the >=, sorry I assumed incorrectly.  however, everything that I said about how to compute it is still valid.  For large sets, you're still likely to end up breaking it into subsets and attempting to find an approximation, as I described.  For very small sets (or for subsets within larger problems), you can check every possible combination to find the closest sub-set.

Comment: thanks, I also think the thing u said is still valid for this problem! so here should I break the target value in example 1000 into small parts? just like breaking the capacity of the package in the 01package problem ?

Comment: @Monzy Zhang You may need to scale the constraint, but you'll have to choose whether to scale it based on a size that is likely to work; for example, in your example with 6 elements, since all of your values in the list are more than 1/10 of the constraint, you wouldn't want to scale it.  If you had a much larger constraint, say, 100000, with a million values in the set where each was less than 1000, you would want to scale the constraint.  To choose, you could sample max,min,avg of the set to determine whether to scale, or just start by scaling a very small amount and work up as needed.

Comment: I get your point. your explanation really helps a lot to me in understanding this problem! thank u !

Answer (score 0):

You can use transaction optimizer from the [EmerCoin wallet](https://github.com/Emercoin/emercoin/blob/master/src/wallet.cpp#L1112).
It exacly does, what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

An approach to solve this problem can be done in two steps:

- define a function which takes a subarray and gives you an evaluation or a score of this subarray so that you can actually compare subarrays and take the best. A function could be simply

  `if(sum(subarray) < 1000) return INFINITY
  else return sum(subarray) - 1000`

  note that you can also use dynamic programming to compute the sum of subarrays
- Assuming that the length of your goal array is `N`, you will need to solve the problems of size 1 to N. If the array's length is 1 then obviously there is one possibility and it's the best. If `size > 1` then we take the solution of the problem with length `size - 1` and we compare it with every subarray containing the last element of the array and we take the best subarray as the solution of the problem with length `size`.

I hope my explanation makes sense